# how to add authentication to aws api gateway call in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm calling AWS APi Gateway from node, using the following options:

```
var post_options = {
        host: 'myurl.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        port: '443'
        path: '/staging/api',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };
```

The call is made in the following way:

```
http.post(post_options, post_data, function(res){
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                console.log(chunk);
            });
        });
```

The response I get back is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: Yl1rUhK7Bmaq57ckHvK1E32tqNqDs4GC078yek3_23_RMefXUGJAdA==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
name: undefined
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: nJ3dotCRum8XudR6v0PinqzDjjPCX3N5TmoM2fNQSJK9BLn8jJEWqg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I think, I'm getting "Bad request" because I did not pass any authentication information to my call.
What is the proper syntax to add such auth information?

Comment: What authentication did you configure on your API endpoint?  If you didn't configure any, there isn't any, and your error is something else.

Comment: my coworker configured that part. I will check with him.

Comment: If it's authentication related, you won't get 400 (Bad request). You would get 401 (Unauthorised) or 403 (Forbidden). Please check if your request is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway doesn't support chunked encoding, is that what you are trying to use on the backend? If the response headers back through API Gateway indicate that we should be using chunked encoding, there might be an issue.

You shouldn't receive this error regardless, but I want to determine more specifics about your API/backend.